# ascii characters in R, howto

Tags: r, ascii

I have a list like this one:

```
> ascii
  [1] "\033" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
 [11] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
 [21] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
 [31] "\032" "\032" "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
 [41] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
 [51] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
 [61] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
 [71] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
 [81] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
 [91] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
[101] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
[111] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"   
[121] "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "0"    "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[131] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[141] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[151] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[161] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[171] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[181] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[191] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[201] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[211] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[221] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[231] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[241] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
[251] "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032" "\032"
```

I'd like to write specific ascii characters in this list (this list is called ascii). For example, I want a space " " where you see "\032". For doing that, i do: ascii[1:32] <- "\032"... but this writes exactly "\032" to those positions... with some characters, for example "\045" it works...

Don't say me please to do ascii[1:32] <- " ", because I'd like to introduce other ascii characters in the list and it would be better for me to write numbers than the characters...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:  updated**

R just uses numbers.  so for example

```
myascii<-c(65,66,67)

rawToChar(as.raw(myascii))
```

gives ABC

so all you have to do is instead of "\066"  just use 66  when modifying the array

Comment: I'll post in just a sec converting the strings to number

Comment: since you seem to be actually writing the numbers yourself, there's no need to convert "\066" to 66